# How to highlight v-list-item upon click? (Vue)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, user-interface

I have a side menu that changes depending on the router model selected. I am trying to have the page that is selected be highlighted upon click. I want this behavior on my submenus: https://codepen.io/Jayesh_v/pen/eYBjLrq

Here are the first two submenus in my code: [UI of the menu currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4cXc.png)

```
 <v-list-group sub-group :value="true">
            <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>General settings</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </template>
            <v-list-item
              v-if="
                (Router_Obj.is_individual_router == true ||
                  Router_Obj.is_individual_router == false) &&
                (routerDetail.router_model == 'FX20' ||
                  routerDetail.group_model == 'FX20')
              "
              value="true"
              @click="menu_change('Main Wi-Fi')"
            >
              <v-list-item-title>Main Wi-Fi</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item
              v-if="
                routerDetail.router_model.substring(0, 4) == 'RG21' ||
                routerDetail.group_model.substring(0, 4) == 'RG21'
              "
              @click="menu_change('Main Wi-Fi')"
            >
              <v-list-item-title>Main Wi-Fi</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item
              v-if="
                (Router_Obj.is_individual_router == true ||
                  Router_Obj.is_individual_router == false) &&
                (routerDetail.router_model == 'FX20' ||
                  routerDetail.group_model == 'FX20')
              "
              @click="menu_change('Guest Wi-Fi')"
            >
              <v-list-item-title>Guest Wi-Fi</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item
              v-if="
                routerDetail.router_model.substring(0, 4) == 'RG21' ||
                routerDetail.group_model.substring(0, 4) == 'RG21'
              "
              @click="menu_change('Guest Wi-Fi')"
            >
              <v-list-item-title>Guest Wi-Fi</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
```

I have tried class binding but I can't seem to figure out a way to use the same variable for all the different submenus. Instead of using "isActive = false/true", I feel like I need to use "isMainWifiActive" and "isGuestWifiActive". As you can tell, this would get pretty long and complex if I tried to add a different variable for each submenu. Do I need to create a whole new variable for each submenu, or can I somehow use the same variable for all of them?

Edit:

Like @DvidSilva suggested, I created a second variable called "openMenu" and tracked which page was open using that variable. (i.e. openMenu = "Main Wi-Fi") I then used conditional class binding to apply my 'active' class when the openMenu matches the page it's on. Here is what one of my v-list-items looks like:

```
  <v-list-item
      v-if="
        routerDetail.router_model.substring(0, 4) == 'RG21' ||
        routerDetail.group_model.substring(0, 4) == 'RG21'
      "
      :class="{'active': openMenu == 'Main Wi-Fi'}"

      @click="menu_change('Main Wi-Fi')"
    >
      <v-list-item-title>Main Wi-Fi</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
```

Comment: You could try a different variable name to store the current open panel, like OpenedMenu='guestwifi'

Comment: @DvidSilva I like where this is going, but I'm not sure how OpenedMenu would allow me to apply classes based on the v-list-item. Can you use if statements inside a class binding?

Answer (score 0):

If you are usin Vuetify 2.x, `v-list-group` has a prop `active-class` when an item is selected:
https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-group/

you can update it and add your custom css class like your codepen example.

Comment: I tried using the active-class prop, but it only seems to work for my v-list-group. I need it to be active on my v-list-item. Active-class doesn't seem to work on my v-list-item. Not sure why tho, as it is in the documentation